# I need to use colorful icons in react native. Is it possible to use icons like react-icons/fc?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I tried to add react-icons/fc in my expo project but i encountered with an error. I need to place a colorful icon in the drawer but expo supports only some default icons which doesn't suit the UI.

I can't even place the downloaded icon in the drawer..

Please Help

Need to use colorful icons in expo

Answer (score 0):

You can try `react-native-vector-icons` it have lots of icons may it useful to you. See [Icon directory](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/).

Answer (score -1):

try [bootstrap icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com) it allows you to use colorful icons.

Answer (score -1):

`react-icons` works for HTML. For native, you should use other libraries such as `react-native-vector-icons`.